# MongoDB install errors / E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg, crunchbang

I'm trying to install things in Linux (Crunchbang Linux - a derivation of Debian), and I'm getting errors which point towards mongodb-20gen.

When I try to remove it using :-

```
  cometbill@Linuxn00b:~$ sudo apt-get remove mongodb-10gen
```

I get ...

```
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree
 Reading state information... Done
 The following packages will be REMOVED:
   mongodb-10gen
 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
 1 not fully installed or removed.
 After this operation, 221 MB disk space will be freed.
 Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 81657 files and directories currently installed.)
 Removing mongodb-10gen ...
 arg: remove
 invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/mongodb not found.
 dpkg: error processing mongodb-10gen (--remove):
  subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 100
 invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/mongodb not found.
 dpkg: error while cleaning up:
  subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 100
 Errors were encountered while processing:
  mongodb-10gen
 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I read something on here for similar errors with MongoDB, and it
 suggested removing mongo-clients, so, I tried:-

```
 cometbill@Linuxn00b:~$ sudo apt-get remove mongodb-clients
```

and get:-

```
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree
 Reading state information... Done
 Package 'mongodb-clients' is not installed, so not removed
 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
 1 not fully installed or removed.
 After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
 Setting up mongodb-10gen (2.4.6) ...
 invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/mongodb not found.
 dpkg: error processing mongodb-10gen (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 100
 Errors were encountered while processing:
  mongodb-10gen
 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

on schaiba's advice, I tried :-

```
cometbill@Linuxn00b:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
```

and got :-

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up mongodb-10gen (2.4.6) ...
invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/mongodb not found.
dpkg: error processing mongodb-10gen (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 100
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mongodb-10gen
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Try apt-get install -f .

Comment: Thanks @schaiba, that also didn't work - Updated text of question to include this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[This AskUbuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/195950/package-system-broken-e-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1) solved the problem for me; I edited `/var/lib/dpkg/status` and removed the section that was causing problems.

Comment: This is just the worst possible solution.

Comment: @Braiam You can't just say "this is bad" and then not offer any alternative, or reason as to why it is bad.

Comment: If you see my comment on the other answer that you followed, you will notice why.

Answer (score 4):

Since the error message complains about `/etc/init.d/mongodb` not existing, try creating that file. This is probably enough to make progress in this case.

In general, when an installation or removal script fails, look at `/var/lib/dpkg/info/$PACKAGE.{preinst,postinst,prerm,postrm}`. If it's a shell script, add `set -x` just below the `#!` line to make it print a trace. Edit the script if necessary to correct the error, then run `apt-get -f install`.